# IIS responds with "401 Unauthorized" without waiting for request's body

Tags: iis, http, iis-8.5, http-authentication

I noticed that our IIS 8.5 returns "`401 Unauthorized`" response to non-authenticated HTTP request right after receiving its headers, without waiting for the body:

*the client:*

```
POST /some/protected/page HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.org
Content-Length: 4666
```

*the server, without waiting for the rest:*

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
```

*the client goes on:*

```
<xml>some large XML block of 4666 bytes in total</xml>
```

Now, by itself it doesn't represent a problem, but our load balancer (FortiGate v6.0.3) decided to be smart, so it drops the request's body after seeing the "`401 Unauthorized`" response. And this, as I understand, causes next request over the same TCP pipe to fail, since the server interprets next bytes as a payload promised by the "`Content-Length: 4666`" header.

**The question**: is it possible to make IIS to wait for the whole request before responding with `401`?

Comment: I don't think IIS is doing anything wrong here. You should instead ask if it's possible to make the FortiGate behave sensibly. Or it could be that you have a completely different problem than the problem you think you have. You should describe the actual problem in more detail, not just your proposed solution.

Comment: I'm not saying it's doing anything wrong. Just looking for possible workarounds.

Comment: Are you **requiring** mutual-authenticated connections and then attempting a non-authenticated connection? Make sure the system supports/allows what you're trying to do. Possibly you're rejecting HTTP traffic or enforcing a form of HTTPS that the client doesn't support, or requiring Client Authentication, etc.

Comment: It's a very standard thing with Windows authentication: browser submits first request un-authenticated, then gets 401 error and re-attempts the request with Kerberos ticket / NTLM challenge response in the Authorization header. When a new TCP connection is open, the process repeats.